# Laravel mix watch ignore multiple folders using watchOptions

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, chokidar

Using Laravel Mix 6 trying to disable changes to `/resources/view` from rebuilding resources.

> ignored (anymatch-compatible definition) Defines files/paths to be
> ignored. The whole relative or absolute path is tested, not just
> filename. If a function with two arguments is provided, it gets called
> twice per path - once with a single argument (the path), second time
> with two arguments (the path and the fs.Stats object of that path).

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    watchOptions: { ignored: ['/node_modules/', '/resources/views/'] }
});
```

If I try with function:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: (path) => ["node_modules", "resources/views"].some(s => path.includes(s))
    }
});
```

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been
> initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - configuration.watchOptions.ignored should be one of these:    [non-empty string, ...] | RegExp | non-empty string    -> Ignore some
>   files from watching (glob pattern or regexp).    Details:
>
>   - configuration.watchOptions.ignored should be an array:
>     [non-empty string, ...]
>   - configuration.watchOptions.ignored should be an instance of RegExp.
>   - configuration.watchOptions.ignored should be a non-empty string.
>     -> A single glob pattern for files that should be ignored from watching.